# CPU jumps when scrolling a div in chrome

Tags: html, performance, google-chrome, vue.js

I get a very long string from the server, that contains text and html tags and I render those line in a scrollable div. When I click the scroll bar with the mouse and drag it, it scrolls fine,
but when I use the mousewheel, it barely moves and the CPU jumps to 60-100.

here's the div css:

```
background-color: #000;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    padding: 0 20px 10px 20px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #dfe3eb;
    cursor: text;
    overflow: auto;
    min-height: 400px;
    height: calc(100vh - 316px);
    line-height: 1.4;
    will-change: transform;
```

I've noticed that if I remove `white-space: pre-wrap;` performance is much better but I need it since I want to render the spaces/new lines.

I tried adding `will-change: transform;` but it didn't help, any idea?

Comment: Chrome has a built-in profiler. If that doesn't help, provide a [mcve].

Comment: @rustyx Profiling doesn't tell me anything I didn't know, there's a lot of Painting going on. As for an example, I'm working on it.